# btrfs filesystem resize "no enough free space"

Tags: btrfs

I use two identical 1TB disks with btrfs, non raid atm. I have used a few 100 GB in the past and now copy large files to it and so I started to check how it works and if everything is okay; But it seems somehow I need to allocate more space and cannot figure out how.

```
root@k17:~# btrfs filesystem df /media/konnertz/1abdc5b6-d22e-45f4-93b1-b52bfbc01ee4/
Data, single: total=794.01GiB, used=786.99GiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=96.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=17.01GiB, used=1.05GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=360.00MiB, used=0.00B


root@k17:~# btrfs filesystem show 
Label: none  uuid: 1abdc5b6-d22e-45f4-93b1-b52bfbc01ee4
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 787.79GiB
    devid    1 size 931.51GiB used 405.02GiB path /dev/sde
    devid    2 size 931.51GiB used 406.00GiB path /dev/sdd
```

I tried resizing

```
root@k17:~# btrfs fi resize +50g /media/konnertz/1abdc5b6-d22e-45f4-93b1-b52bfbc01ee4/ 
Resize '/media/konnertz/1abdc5b6-d22e-45f4-93b1-b52bfbc01ee4/' of '+50g'    
ERROR: unable to resize '/media/konnertz/1abdc5b6-d22e-45f4-93b1-b52bfbc01ee4/': no enough free space
```

How is it supposed to work?
(it is non-root filesystem)

**UPDATE**
It seems it's automatically done... cool. I just kept copying data and now it shows 808G total which was 791G before

```
root@k17:~# btrfs filesystem df /media/konnertz/1abdc5b6-d22e-45f4-93b1-b52bfbc01ee4/
Data, single: total=808.01GiB, used=800.28GiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=96.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=17.01GiB, used=1.07GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=368.00MiB, used=36.00KiB
```

Comment: Are you sure the disks are 2TB each? The value of `931.51GiB` translates to (almost exactly) 1TB and this is common for 1TB disks. Probably the filesystem was purposely created smaller than it could be, but please confirm. The output of `lsblk` should be enough.

Comment: oh yes you're right; these disks are 1TB each, I will edit my question; But somehow I need to allocate the missing >100GB ?

Comment: I don't know where this `>100GB` of yours came from. I think the btrfs filesystem will take up to `931.51GiB + 931.51GiB` when it needs to. `btrfs fi df` can be confusing, I know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has answered the question in the body of the question

Comment: i would move the answer from body to answer in 2 days

Comment: @Kamil, the >100GB was also wrong assumption from me; I have a few mdadm raid 1 running and still think in terms of 1+1TB disks = 1TB space. sorry for confusion!